# jsplumb could not connect nested div elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb 1.7.10 and bootstrap 3.3.5. I could not connect buttons on nested divs. I also used container.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkurt/3wysvyq7/1). Try to connect source0 to targets.

How can i connect theese buttons?

JS Code:

```
 jsPlumb.bind("ready", function () {
    jsPlumb.setContainer($("container"));
    jsPlumb.makeSource("src_0", {
        maxConnections: 1,
        isSource: true
    });


    jsPlumb.makeTarget("tgt_0", {
        maxConnections: 1,
        isTarget: true
    });
    jsPlumb.makeTarget("tgt_1", {
        maxConnections: 1,
        isTarget: true
    });
    jsPlumb.makeTarget("tgt_2", {
        maxConnections: 1,
        isTarget: true
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="portlet light bordered">
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <div class="row" id="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="portlet box blue">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Keys1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body text-center">
                            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                                <button id="src_0" class="btn blue" type="button" style="width:200px">src0</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="portlet box green-sharp">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Keys2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body text-center">
                            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                                <button id="tgt_0" class="btn blue" type="button" style="width:200px">tgt0</button>
                                <button id="tgt_1" class="btn blue" type="button" style="width:200px">tgt1</button>
                                <button id="tgt_2" class="btn blue" type="button" style="width:200px">tgt2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: weird. it works, but the connectors are positioned incorrectly (try dropping the connection to the right of the targets : it actually creates a "floating" connection).

And jsplumb.repaintEverything() does not seem to fix this behavior.

Comment: Yes it is weired. If you add "jsPlumb.addEndpoint("tgt_0", { isTarget:true});" (http://jsfiddle.net/kkurt/3wysvyq7/1) JSPlumb adds endpoint far away from button.